# Values from meta-box not on $_POST

Tags: custom-post-types, post-meta, metabox

I have a meta-box for a cpt and can't get the values from the form to `update_post_meta`

**cpt declaration:**

```
    function hgod_fichas()
    {
        $labels = array( … );

        $args = array(
            'label' => __('Fichas', 'hgodinho'),
            'description' => __('Fichamento', 'hgodinho'),
            'labels' => $labels,
            'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'revisions'),
            'hierarchical' => false,
            'public' => true,
            'show_ui' => true,
            'show_in_menu' => true,
            'menu_position' => 5,
            'show_in_admin_bar' => true,
            'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
            'can_export' => true,
            'has_archive' => 'fichas',
            'exclude_from_search' => false,
            'publicly_queryable' => true,
            'capability_type' => 'post',
            'show_in_rest' => true,
        );
        register_post_type('hgod_fichas', $args);
    }
```

**meta-box declaration:**

```
    function hgod_add_metabox($post_type)
    {
        $post_type = get_post_type();
    
        add_meta_box(
            $post_type . '_metabox',
            __('Ficha', 'hgod'),
            $post_type . '_render',
            $post_type,
        );
    }
```

**meta-box callback:**

```
    function hgod_fichas_render( $post )
    {
        $mb = get_post_meta($post->ID);   
        wp_nonce_field( basename( __FILE__ ), '_hgod_fichas_mb_nonce');
        ?>
        <p>
            <label for="ficha_tipo">Tipo:
            </label>
            <select name="ficha_tipo" id="ficha_tipo">
                <option value="none" selected disable hidden>Selecione o…</option>
                <option value="livro">livro</option>
                <option value="texto">texto</option>
                <option value="webpage">webpage</option>
                <option value="imagem">imagem</option>
                <option value="video">video</option>
                <option value="audio">audio</option>
                <option value="codigo">codigo</option>
            </select>
        </p>
    …

    }
```

**Save function**

the problem relies here, I cant get the values from nounce neither the select field, or any other input value on my `hgod_fichas_render()` function, so I get returned on the very first conditional of this function:

```
    function hgod_save_ficha($post_id){
    
        if ( ! isset( $_POST['_hgod_fichas_mb_nonce'] ) ) {
            return; // RETURN HERE
        }
     
        if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['_hgod_fichas_mb_nonce'], '_hgod_fichas_mb_nonce' ) ) {
            return;
        }
     
        if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) {
            return;
        }
     
        if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_hgod_fichas', $post_id ) ) {
            return;
        }
    
        $tipo_ficha = $_POST['ficha_tipo'];
        
        $update_ficha = update_post_meta($post_id, '_hgod_ficha_livro_autor', $tipo_ficha);
        if ( !$update_ficha ){
            wp_die('nao salvou' );
        } 
        
    }
```

Can anyone throw a light on this?

Comment: Are you checking on the navigator dev tools network section if the fields are actually being sent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I get returned on the very first conditional

Are you sure? Because it seems to me that it's likely the second one which verifies the nonce.

```php
if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['_hgod_fichas_mb_nonce'], '_hgod_fichas_mb_nonce' ) ) {
    return;
}
```

But even if the first conditional is also exiting the function, you should know that the *second parameter* for [`wp_verify_nonce()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_verify_nonce/) should match the *first parameter* that you passed to [`wp_nonce_field()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nonce_field/).

Therefore,

- Because you used `wp_nonce_field( basename( __FILE__ ), '_hgod_fichas_mb_nonce');`
- Then you should use `wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['_hgod_fichas_mb_nonce'], basename( __FILE__ ) )`.